# What are the origins of rgb.txt?

Tags: x11, colors, history

Where did the list of [X11 color names](http://cvsweb.xfree86.org/cvsweb/xc/programs/rgb/rgb.txt?rev=1.1&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup) come from? Every resource I've found online claims the origin is unknown, but it must be recorded somewhere. The best information I've found was in an [archived discussion page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia_talk%3aWikiProject_Color/Archive&oldid=493850484) at Wikipedia's Wikiproject Color:

> The X11 color names were designed (...) by computer scientists making things up as they went along.

and

> It is true the X11 colors were the work of mostly clueless grad students

Is there anything more substantial about the origins of the X11 color names?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Waldir: Look at the original post before Sukminder edited it.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman: Sukminder's edit only changed a typo. Maybe you meant Michael Mrozek's edit instead? In any case, the question was downvoted *after* his edit, so I'm not really sure what, in either my original post, or the version after his edit, offended the principles of unix.SX. Hence my question.

Comment: I made a couple of errors here. You are correct; I did mean Michael Mrozek's edit. I somehow missed that I was replying to the question's original poster in the comments. My sincerest apologies; I meant no insult. I meant to point out the possibility that the downvoters disliked the style of the original post. If the downvotes were received after the post's style was rennovated, then they seem truly unjustified.

Comment: Isn't think kinda in the docs? The [readme](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rdebath/SLS-1.02/master/usr/src/X11/mit/rgb/others/README) in the /other subfolder is actually a surprisingly fun read. And it talk about various named people sitting down with crayons and paints. (NB the link i posted is to someones githiub mirror, but it is the same as the one that is buried deep in the XOrg ftp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ones used today is mainly from release X11R4. *See below.* That is: not only by name but also by definition.

Looking at Wikipedias entry on [X11 color names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) it states that *they*
were defined by [Bob Scheifler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Scheifler) of MIT's Laboratory for Computer Science.
As he lead out the birth of X back in 1984 that is probably correct – but
the reference has no such claims.

Looking at one of the first releases, [X.V10R3](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X10R3/X.V10R3.tar.gz), another name pops out
when looking at the code, namely Tony Della Fera of MIT Laboratory for Computer Science, [Digital Equipment Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Equipment_Corporation) (DEC) and Project Athena.

He did at least commit the `rgb.c` file back in 86 ;)

```
static char *rcsid_rgb_c = "$Header: rgb.c,v 10.4 86/02/01 15:55:22 tony Rel $";
```

In the following release, [X.V10R4](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X10R4/X.V10R4.tar.gz), he is also credited in the man pages
for e.g. [X](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/x10r4/doc/mann/X.n) and [xload](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/x10r4/doc/mann/xload.n).

---

Anyhow is it rather safe bet to guess Bob Scheifler had at least a big part
in compiling the list given his role in the core start.

*(A note from [net.unix-wizards](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/net.unix-wizards/yjB8IY3gQ8A), X Window System Release 3 (Protocol Version 10) – Jim Gettys, Paul Asente, Brian Reid and Bob Scheifler on V vs W vs X on
origins, credit, etc.)*

---

But; that does not mean he or they actually coined the names. It could also
origin form the [Ultrix Window Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrix_Window_Manager) as it got included in X. It at
least uses color naming like Aquamarine, MediumSeaGreen etc.

---

<sub>[LINFO X](http://www.linfo.org/x.html) Origins of X.</sub>

---

## Colors by revision

---

### X10R3 - X11R1 ; 1986 - 1987

The colors for [release](http://ftp.x.org/pub/) ([Dates from here](http://www.x.org/wiki/Releases/History)):

```
10R3 ca. 1986-06-07
10R4 ca. 1986-12-25
11R1 ca. 1987-09-18
```

are the same. 69 colors given by lowercase separated words and upper camel case.

E.g.:

```
255 240 245     lavender blush
255 240 245     LavenderBlush
```

---

### X11R2, ca. 1988-03-24

In release [11R2](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R2/) two new colors came along namely:

```
Brown   165 42  42
Gray    192 192 192
Grey    192 192 192
```

Yes, gray was by two names. From notes it also seems some people was happy
about this because they always forgot if it was *grey* or *gray* – ref.
[xfd](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xfd.1.html) change suggestion by [HP Labs](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R3/):

```
X.V11R3/doc/bugs/database/closed/xfd/11
```

---

### X11R3, ca. 1988-10-27

In release [11R3](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R3/) there was a few changes `SandyBrown` came along. 
Until now white had been RGB `252 252 252` but now was changed to 
`255 255 255`.

101 shades of gray was also introduced. Going from

```
gray0     0   0   0
gray1     3   3   3
gray2     5   5   5
# ... to
gray100 255 255 255
# with a 3-2 interval.
```

That would mean, as both *grey* and *gray* was used – 202 new names.

Gray variants was used earlier as well but then mere in the form of:

```
menu = "  CREATE WINDOW  " {
Black:      !"xterm -r -bw 3 &"
White:      !"xterm -bw 3 &"
"Gray #1":  !"xterm -bw 3 -bg LimeGreen -fg Black &"
"Gray #2":  !"xterm -bw 3 -bg MediumSeaGreen -fg White &"
"Gray #3":  !"xterm -bw 3 -bd White -bg DarkSlateGray -fg White &"
}
```

and various shades dynamically generated in C, and bitmaps such as gray3.bitmap:

```
#define gray3_width 16
#define gray3_height 16
static short gray3_bits[] = {
   0x1111, 0x0000, 0x4444, 0x0000,
   0x1111, 0x0000, 0x4444, 0x0000,
   0x1111, 0x0000, 0x4444, 0x0000,
   0x1111, 0x0000, 0x4444, 0x0000};
```

used to tile backgrounds etc.

---

### X11R4, 1989-01-29

Then by release [11R4](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R4/) came a major change
(X11R4/mit/rgb/others/README) by the hands of Paul Raveling at Information 
Sciences Institute (ISI) of the University of Southern California and John C 
Thomas at Tektronix, Inc. Oregon (at least).

They removed two and added 376 new colors but also redefined almost all colors.
*These values are what stands today.* A few has been added later.

Thomas, funny enough, among other things, did tuning by going trough 72 Crayola
crayons. Paul Raveling then did further tuning using his own HP monitor.

The [README](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11/X11-0.40/xc/programs/rgb/others/README) speaks for itself.

- The suggestion post from Paul Raveling *[A different X11 RGB database](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.windows.x/PDXZCruNDuI)*.
- Color list post *[X11 color database](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.windows.x/AYPozZhQxok)*.

[image: Crayola crayons]

<sub>Image from http://blog.flauntme.com/2010/02/17/diy-crayon-lipstick/</sub>

Example of tuning:

```
-OLD-                     -NEW-
BlueViolet 159  95 159    BlueViolet  138  43 226
DarkGreen   47  79  47    DarkGreen     0 100   0
Firebrick  142  35  35    Firebrick   178  34  34
```

Added colors:

```
AliceBlue        Gainsboro       Linen          PaleGoldenrod   RosyBrown  
AntiqueWhite     GhostWhite      MediumPurple   PaleTurquoise   RoyalBlue  
Azure            Honeydew        MintCream      PaleVioletRed   SaddleBrown
Beige            HotPink         MistyRose      PapayaWhip      Seashell   
Bisque           Lavender        Moccasin       PeachPuff       SlateGray  
BlanchedAlmond   LavenderBlush   NavajoWhite    Peru            SlateGrey  
burlywood        LawnGreen       OldLace        PowderBlue      Snow       
DodgerBlue       LemonChiffon    OliveDrab      Purple          Tomato     
WhiteSmoke  

DarkGoldenrod    DarkOrange      DarkSeaGreen   DeepPink   
DarkKhaki        DarkSalmon      DarkViolet     DeepSkyBlue

LightCoral       LightGoldenrodYellow   LightSeaGreen    LightSlateGray
LightCyan        LightPink              LightSkyBlue     LightSlateGrey
LightGoldenrod   LightSalmon            LightSlateBlue   LightYellow
```

And also 312 shades like:

```
snow1 snow2 snow3 snow4
seashell1 seashell2 seashell3 seashell4
```

etc.

Removed:

```
MediumForestGreen  107 142  35
MediumGoldenrod    234 234 173
```

---

### X11R5, 1994-05-18

Gray and grey was changed from `192 192 192` to `190 190 190`.

---

### X11R6, 1995-03-02

New additions:

```
DarkBlue   DarkCyan   DarkMagneta   DarkGray   LightGreen   DarkRed
```

### X11R6 - DD.

None I'm aware of. Notice Wikipedia also list six W3C colors plus teal, olive, crimson, fuchsia, indigo and an alias for cyan as aqua.

Comment: That was incredibly informative. Thanks a lot! I'll see what I can do about integrating this information back into Wikipedia :)

Comment: Too bad there's no info on individual names. I'm curious how "AliceBlue" and "Peru" ended up in the list for example.